# Query the database through a query string

Tags: asp.net

I wanted to create a URL like `http://localhost/menu.aspx/?id` so that on typing this, it displays all the id's in the database.
for eg:
134

123

543

234

may be the id's which should be displayed after fetching from the database. However, it should be displayed as it it is without any control or without arranging in any gird etc. How can that be done?

Comment: This is too broad of a question, it's not clear what aspects you are having troubles with. You might be better off to break this down into smaller more specific questions.

Comment: My query is "When I visit this `url`, the id's should be fetched from the database and displayed on the web page". I know how to query the db for the Id's but how do I display them on the webpage, when I visit this URL?

Comment: What language are you using, what code have you got so far?

Comment: you `select [data] from [table] where [id] = @id` - then you use some magic to display the [data] on the page. `<%= Eval("Data") %>` might work, or `@model.Data` could also work. But really it all depends on what the frig you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for filtering data across two pages, I've a sample here...

Page1.aspx

### [image: Page1.aspx]

Page2.aspx 
[image: Page2.aspx]

1. Page1 you have two linkbuttons whose
   text is Product Ids and Product
   Names repectively
2. These linkbuttons have Postbackurl set to a different page - ~page2.aspx?column=ids and ~page2.aspx?column=names to list out all the ids / names from db.

Page1 markup:

```
<asp:LinkButton Text='Product Ids'  runat="server" CommandArgument='Submit' PostBackUrl='~/StackOverflowQs/QueryDBByQueryString.aspx?column=ids'>
</asp:LinkButton>

    <br />

<asp:LinkButton Text='Product Names'  runat="server" CommandArgument='Submit' PostBackUrl="~/StackOverflowQs/QueryDBByQueryString.aspx?column=names">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Page2 markup:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID='SqlDataSource1' runat='server'
        SelectCommand='select productid, productname from products' 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NORTHWNDConnectionString  %>">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:Repeater ID='Repeater1' runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <ul>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
           <li>
                <%# Eval("ProductID") %>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </ul>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

    <asp:Repeater ID='Repeater2' runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <ul>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <%# Eval("ProductName") %>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </ul>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

This page has two Repeaters and a sqldatasource, repeater1 has item template to display all the product id whereas repeater2's item template displays product name.
Based on the query string the appropriate repeater is set to show the data by binding its datasource, as in the code snippet below.

Page2 code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String queryString = Request.QueryString["column"];

        if(queryString.Equals("ids"))
        {
            Repeater1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
            Repeater1.DataBind();
        }
        else if(queryString.Equals("names"))
        {
            Repeater2.DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1";
            Repeater2.DataBind();
        }

    }
```